# How do I remove the shortcut arrow emblem from application launcher icons in desktop on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: icons, gnome-shell, .desktop, desktop-icons, emblem

My Ubuntu version is 20.04 LTS. How can I remove the shortcut arrow emblems from the icons?

[image: Just like this,how can I remove the arrows between icons]

Comment: Are you sure they are real files/folders, not shortcuts?

Comment: They are desktop files,not shortcuts.

Comment: @PRATAP indeed not necessarily a duplicate: remains to be tested. Even on `.desktop` launchers, the Desktop Icons extension seems to add arrows.

Comment: @pomsky my ubuntu version is 20.04 LTS,do you know how to remove the icons?

Comment: @PRATAP,sorry.it has no effect on my ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: @wulikunkun Please edit your question and add the output of `ls -l ~/Desktop`. Let's see if they are real files or desktop entries a.k.a. shortcuts.